# Why is $f(x)= \frac{1}{x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$ not Lebesgue integrable but Gauge integrable?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Studying Lebesgue Integration and have come across the following function on Wikipedia: $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$
I was wondering why the above function is not Lebesgue integrable? And why is it Gauge integrable?

Comment: What do you mean by "Gauge integrable"?

Comment: @uniquesolution the [Gauge Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral) is a very well-known concept.